# PHP или python: вопрос структуры

Tags: python, php, internet-explorer

Это не холивар, а конкретная задача. Есть база на постгрес. И ей что-то плоховато стало в последнее время. Имеем на данном этапе - cron запускает python скрипт, который выгребает данные для графиков за последние сутки раз в 5 минут. Итого имеем в текстовом файле на сервере 250к записей (ид графика, значение, время). На php с помощью ajax выгребаю данные и парсю в зависимости от графика, какие данные отображать. Вроде бы лепота. фф грузит данные за 1сек, но ослик обрабатывает данные 10сек. Так что прирост производительности невысокий.

Внимание, знатоки, вопрос - как это дело оптимизировать? Мне кажется, что питон должен быть быстрее в парсинге значений по айдишнику, но  сможет ли пхп страница запустить скрипт и как передать значения тэгов?

А если сделать это с помощью пхп, то передать значения тэгов и время с помщью гета или поста дело плевое. Но это опять же будет парситься сервером и вроде как из пустого в порожнее? Кто как бы делал\сделал?

UPD

Для простоты - хочу реализовать схему (запрос к базе из python -> создание файла ВСЕХ значений -> парсинг данных php\python -> конечный пользователь из php страницы обращается к данным только для своих графиков)
заглох на интрументарии парсинга текстового файла. php - вроде легко, но как с производительностью? python - вродь крутой ЯП, а как передать ид тэгов и вообще возможно ли?

```
        разница файла и запроса к базе
```

[image]

Comment: Так в чем проблема? В том, что ослик долго грузится? Так при чем здесь БД, если в FF все нормально? Может, посмотреть, что не так с осликом?

И при чем здесь PHP или python? Из базы данные берутся базой, сам PHP/Python ничего не парсит.

Comment: если выгребать из базы, то это и есть пресловутые 10 секунд. фф, конечно, решает, но  приходится поддерживать ослика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нанять DB-админа, который настроит базу, индексы и прочие, раз прогерам лень.
2. Нанять DB-developer`а, который будет писать грамотно sql запросы, раз прогерам лень.
3. Агрегировать данные для удобной работы.
4. Начать работать непосредственно с БД, а не гигабайтным файлом и его парсингом.
5. Написать api для получения данных клиентом.
6. Написать клиент на любом языке, который выводит график, используя легковесные плагины.

Это если я правильно понял ваш вопрос. Я работаю с гиганским количеством данных, и все довольно-таки шустро работает, хотя вижу, что можно быстрее, чем и занимаюсь.

Comment: Это, конечно, хорошо.  
1. База настроена, много пользователей просто. Данные динамические, и админ говорит, что индексировать их бессмысленно.  
2. Вопрос открыт, хотя не думаю, что можно написать проще.  
3. Вопрос спорный.
4. Работа с бд медленнее, чем с файлом.  
5. Пункт выше. Так было сделано до этого.  
6. Используется js. На данном этапе такой конкретный рефаторинг не нужен однозначно.

Comment: Очень интересно, в базе динамические данные это как? Это вы на лету меняете структуру БД и создаете новые таблицы или у Вас база написана с игнорированием нормальных форм со всеми вытекающими? К тому же хорошо сделанная база с кэшем не будет работать медленнее парсинга текстового файла тем же сервером с помощью пхп.

--------

Второй момент - что у Вас там такого на JS понаписано, что разброс в принятии данных клиентом составляет аж 10 секунд для разных браузеров? Как бы сервер тут уже не причем, его дело отдать данные и делает он это одинаково для обоих браузеров(по идее так заведено).

Comment: http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2014/07/highcharthighstock.html вот так графики строю. а вот насчет ядра осла и фф - тут стоит поспорить. фф 2015 года и ие 2007 - разница в технологиях хотя бы (ие 9). динамические данные  - речь про то что они добавляются каждые 30 сек

Comment: @anunak, вы не понимаете. IE/FF - это клиент, сервер может быть связан с ними только тем по сколько он отдает данные. Серверу не интересно - IE это или FF. Если для FF все хорошо работает, а для IE плохо, значит надо смотреть - почему для IE все плохо. Смотреть на стороне клиента, а не сервера. У вас может плагин какой или прокси на IE стоит и он все данные через себя гоняет.

Если бы для FF время было 10 секунд - тогда можно было бы сервер смотреть, а сейчас вы по звездам пытаетесь пол ребенка угадать.

А все ваши "оптимизации" - работа с ломом в микроэлектроннике.

Comment: >> 4. Работа с бд медленнее, чем с файлом

Вы это апачу, микрософту и ораклу скажите. А то они, бедные, свои базы пишут, т.к. думают что с файлами работать, во-первых, не удобно, а, во-вторых, медленнее. Вот ведь наивные, да?

Comment: @BOPOH, да там спецы одни. Один - индексы не нужны, второй - файлы быстрее.)

Comment: из базы выгребаются и агрегируются множество значений. математика сильно тормозит этот процесс. а вот когда когда данные лежат в удобочитаемом виде то их читать проще.

Comment: @anunak, лол. Пункт 3-й в моем ответе =)